# Restart process using execve: Cannot get exclusive lock after restart

Tags: c, linux, exec, system-calls

I need to restart process using the common function `restart(...)` for all processes from my library. Client code should not do any extra work for restart.

I use `execve()` system call for restart. The example below suggests that the process may have file locks locks that are from the outside of scope of `restart(...)` function.

```
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOCKFILE "./test_exec_restart.lock"

extern char ** environ;

void restart(char ** argv)
{
    char * new_argv[] = { argv[0], NULL };
    int res = execve(new_argv[0], new_argv, environ);

    fprintf(stderr, "execve() error: %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(-3);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int do_exec = 0;
    if (argc > 1 && strncmp(argv[1], "-e", 2) == 0)
        do_exec = 1;

    printf("do_exec: %d\n", do_exec);

    FILE* file = fopen(LOCKFILE, "w+");
    if (file == NULL)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open lockfile, error: %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }   
    if (flock(fileno(file), LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) < 0)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot exclusive lock, error: %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -2; 
    }   

    if (do_exec)
        restart(argv);

    if (flock(fileno(file), LOCK_UN) < 0)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot unlock, error: %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -4; 
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This example gets lock error after restart:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
$ ./main -e
do_exec: 1
do_exec: 0
Cannot exclusive lock, error: 11(Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

What should be done for get exclusive lock after `exec()` so that the client code does not do any extra work for this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the new execution can't lock the file is that it already has the file open and locked. When you execve all open file descriptors are preserved. You're options are:

1. Close the descriptor on exec: Either open with O_CLOEXEC, apply O_CLOEXEC with fdctl, or close manually before exec - the downside of this is the lock is released between the close and the new flock
2. Pass sufficient information to the new process to own the FD: probably passing the FD number in an argument to the new execution.
3. Switch to process-level locking: F_SETLK etc from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html - I think those will allow the new execution to relock the file.

You can mark the Lock filedescriptor O_CLOEXEC, then it will be closed by the execve, and can be reopened by the new process.

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html you can add "e" to the end of the mode for the `fopen` to achieve this.

Comment: I need to restart process using the common method for all processes.
Client code should not do any extra work for restart process.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible - FileDescriptors are preserved (without O_CLOEXEC) over exec, and the lock is connected to the FileDescriptor. Either the FD must be closed, or the process needs to know that the Lock is already held (maybe pass in the FD number in arguments?)

Comment: @OlegUP *I need to restart process using the common method for all processes.*  If "lock, execve, relock" is the common method, it doesn't work, for the very reason posted in this answer.  If the file descriptor gets closed across the call to `execve()`, it's no longer an effective lock file.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted process can't exclusuve lock because it inherited opened files from first process, and trying lock inherited locked file via inherited descriptor that already have lock.

man execve:

```
      By default, file descriptors remain open across an execve().
      File descriptors that are marked close-on-exec are closed; see
      the description of FD_CLOEXEC in fcntl(2).  (If a file
      descriptor is closed, this will cause the release of all
      record locks obtained on the underlying file by this process.
      See fcntl(2) for details.)  POSIX.1 says that if file
      descriptors 0, 1, and 2 would otherwise be closed after a
      successful execve(), and the process would gain privilege
      because the set-user-ID or set-group-ID mode bit was set on
      the executed file, then the system may open an unspecified
      file for each of these file descriptors.  As a general
      principle, no portable program, whether privileged or not, can
      assume that these three file descriptors will remain closed
      across an execve().
```

My solution is close all files, except `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
...
int close_all_files(int lowfd)
{
    DIR* dir = opendir("/proc/self/fd");
    if (dir == NULL)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open directory: '/proc/self/fd', error: %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }   

    struct dirent* ent = NULL;
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {   
        int fd = atoi(ent->d_name);
        if (fd > lowfd)
            close(fd);
    }   
    closedir(dir);

    return 0;
}

void restart(char ** argv)
{
    close_all_files(fileno(stderr));

    char * new_argv[] = { argv[0], NULL };
    int res = execve(new_argv[0], new_argv, environ);

    fprintf(stderr, "execve() error: %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(-3);
}
...
```

It is also possible using `fdwalk(...)` function, but it is possibly not available on all Linux/UNIX systems.

**REM:**  This is bad solution, because active thread that handled signal is unspecified, and all files may be closed during writes in them. This will result in a loss of data consistency.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).